# POST to phpspreadsheet

Tags: php, ajax, post, phpspreadsheet, http-status-code-500

I have a problem with phpspreadsheet.
I need to pass data to a php file generating an excel file.
I can do it with a

```
        window.location.href='pagegeneratingexcel.php?parameter=parvalue';
```

In the pagegenerating excel I can easily retrieve the GET variable.
But I need to pass a number of variables, or arrays, then I should use a POST, instead.
I tried with ajax

```
    postData = { parameter: "parvalue"};


    $.ajax({
        url : "pagegeneratingexcel.php",
        type: "POST",
        data : postData,
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    })
```

but this is giving a **500 error**.
I tried by generating a dynamic form and submitting it...something like:

```
let form = $(document.createElement('form'));
$(form).attr("action", "pagegeneratingexcel.php");
$(form).attr("method", "POST");
$(form).css("display", "none");
    
let input1 = $("<input>")
.attr("type", "text")
.attr("name", "parameter")
.val("parvalue");
$(form).append($(input1));
        
form.appendTo( document.body );
        
$(form).submit();
```

still no way: it gives a **500 error**.

The problem seems to be linked to this line in the pagegeneratingexcel.php file:

```
$spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load("TemplateExport.xlsx");
```

This is where it stops: this instruction (required by my excel file generation, though) seems to be in conflict with a POST of any type while everything works perfectly with a GET:

```
window.location.href='pagegeneratingexcel.php?parameter=parvalue';
```

or - when there is no data passed:

```
window.location.href='pagegeneratingexcel.php';
```

Just for info the pagegeneratingexcel.php is something like

```
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
$spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load("TemplateExport.xlsx"); 

$spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("A1", "MYVALUES");

$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="OUTPUTFILE.xlsx"');
$writer->save('php://output');
```

Comment: A 500 Internal Server Error is a generic status code, not _supposed_ to give too much information away in the frontend. Go check what the error log has to say about the actual error _reason_.

Comment: It is much worse then expected: it gives a 500 error "sometimes". I thought I ad solved. the syntax I use is the one which creates a temporary form...And for some times it worked...now suddenly it doesn't anymore...and I have changed nothing. How can I better specify what kind of error it is?

Comment: What part of go check what the error log has to say, is unclear? That is _always_ the first thing you should do, when you get a 500, and the reason is not immediately obvious. There is no point in guessing, so _go check_ what PHP has to tell you about it.

Comment: I've gone into the php_error file, thanks for the hint. The only error are PHP Notices (Trying to access array offset on value of type int in /Users/nicolacardi/Cartelle/localhost/waldorf/swapp/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Cell/DefaultValueBinder.php ) BUT I find them ALSO if I use the window.location.href procedure. In that case the excel file is downloaded, though.

Comment: You have not shown us how you are actually accessing those parameters you are sending, on the PHP side.

Answer (score 0):

I have sorted it out myself, thanks anyway for your comments CBroe.
The thing is that it looks like the
window.location.href method is structurally different from an ajax POST (still I ignore why) so the right way to do it is to use a dynamic form which was actually my second option, BUT I had forgotten to JSON.stringify arrays which prevented it from passing them...

```
    let form = $(document.createElement('form'));
    $(form).attr("action", "pagegeneratingexcel.php");
    $(form).attr("method", "POST");
    $(form).css("display", "none");
    
    let input1 = $("<input>")
    .attr("type", "text")
    .attr("name", "parameter")
    .val("parvalue");
    $(form).append($(input1));
    

    let inputNomiCampiA = $("<input>")
   .attr("type", "text").attr("name", 
   "nomiCampiA")
   .val(JSON.stringify(nomiCampiA));  //this is the point
   $(form).append($(inputNomiCampiA));
    
    
   form.appendTo( document.body );
   $(form).submit();
   $(form).remove();
```

Obviously pagegeneratingexcel.php needs to json_decode arrays to get them as real arrays